# Convert javascript code to Action script code?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the equivalenet of the following code in Flex/AS3?

```
var elem = document.getElementById('hiddenTestDiv');
elem.innerHTML = '<b><span class="redText">H</span>ello <span>World!</span></b>';
var innerText  = elem.innerText;  // equals 'Hello World!'
var contentLength = elem.innerText.length; // equals 12
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right sort of question.  Asking people to straight-up convert your code is bad form.

Comment: Uh, AFAIK flash doesn't use the DOM... why do you want to do this?

Comment: Is there any Flex code around this?  Or are you just trying to recreate the same thing in Flex?

Comment: You question is unclear. Are you trying to access the the HTML element 'hiddenTestDiv' from inside of the SWF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting basic purpose of your question clearly, i.e.
**Traversing** to **speific element** and getting it **content/text** as well as its content/text **lenght**. if so, this sample may be helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="{getElementByID('txt', this)}">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Text;
            import mx.core.Container;

            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function getElementByID(name:String, container:Container):void
            {
                 var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildByName(name);

                 if (child != null)
                 {
                    Alert.show(Text(child).text+", Length :"+Text(child).text.length.toString());
                    return;
                 }
                 for each(var childContainer:Container in container.getChildren())
                 {
                    getElementByID(name, childContainer);
                 }

            }



        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HBox id="hBox" >
        <mx:Text text="Hello World" name="txt"/>
    </mx:HBox>

</mx:Application>
```

In this Sample function **getElementByID** gets the control by given **name**  in hierarchy of given **container** example using **Application**

hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, there is no 'proper' way to convert Javascript to Flex.  You have to understand that AS3 is object oriented and Javascript isn't.  The base concept behind to two is also VERY different (display list, timeline, frames, events, binding, etc).

The only resemblance between the two is that actionscript is based loosely on ECMAScript and so is Javascript.

For this particular case however, it seems that you're trying to bind new data to a label, but I can't give you any example code because of lack of specifics.

Comment: you are right that basic platform of JS and AS3 are differnt, but its also a fact that both languages are not pure OOPs, Like in AS3 we cant overload method, similarly JS can do some OOPs thing plz ck link http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could put some limited html within the string assigned to the htmlText property.  In the example below I set the bold, font color properties in the mxml component.  That could be done in the html or with actionscript.

```
    <mx:Script><![CDATA[

       function setHiddenText():void{
         hiddenTestText.htmlText = "H";
         hiddenTestText.htmlText = "ello World";
         var contentLength:Number = hiddenTestText.htmlText.length + hiddenTestText.htmlText.length;
       }

        ]]></mx:Script>


    <mx:HBox>
  <mx:Text id="hiddenTestText" fontWeight="bold" color="red"/>
  <mx:Text id="hiddenTestText2" fontWeight="bold"/>
</mx:HBox>
```